# Microsoft LAPS - Not implementing password to custom Admin account

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

I am trying to implement Microsoft LAPS (Local Admin Password Solution) in a VM environment. I currently have a Server 2012 R2 domain controller with a Windows 7 client.

I was able to update the schema without a hitch. I was also able to use powershell to add the right permissions to my 7 machine and to have certain users read access. When using "get-admpwdpassword -computername "computername"" It gives me a password.

I am also trying to set up a custom admin account with the use of a script through group policy. The script creates the user and adds them to the administrators group. As far as I can tell the script works perfectly.

My trouble is that I cannot seem to link the LAPS password with my custom admin. I made sure to enable LAPS Management in group policy along with pointing the LAPS GP to the custom user. However, the custom account still uses the default password which I gave.

I apologize for the wall of text. Any help is appreciated as I am at a loss, and have looked through the documentation more times than I can count.

Comment: Please do not include the answer inside your question. You can add your own answer to the question and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When adding the new user I had to reset the password and do a GP refresh. Once that was done the new password stuck to the user.

Comment: Please accept your answer so the question is marked as "solved" in the system.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using LAPS a while now. My understanding is it is designed only for the local admin. What I've seen regarding 'other users' has always been focused on a renamed local admin account, never multiple accounts.